# Vue3-carousel pagination not working like expected

Tags: pagination, vuejs3, carousel, vue3-carousel

so my problem with this package is that when I set the `itemsToShow` attribute to 2, so there is 2 items per slide, and I have 13 items, then 13 dots will appaear instead of 7. I don't know if it's possible to change the number of dots, but that would be helpful for sure.

Here is a picture what it looks like:

[image]

And I want to achieve to appaer only 7 dots.

Thanks for any help!